# Have an already created thread at all time or create the thread when necessary

Tags: c++, multithreading, usb, mutex

I'm working with a user mode driver for small scale USB devices. My usb reading loop should be very responsive and operations it performs should be very small ( not necessary to be atomic). Like an interrupt service routine in a kernel mode driver. In one processing I need to create a thread and pass some parameters to that thread inside that reading loop.

So I need to know the exact upper limit of that operation. It will not take more than 200mS , or something like that.

Next alternative is to do the thread initialization at the device initialization time ( probing time ) and then sleep that thread waiting till I signal it from the reading thread. But in this scenario the thread is always running and it would be costly.

What is the best option ? My platform is linux, and they said in linux, thread creation have very short operation. I need to decide what is best. Keep the thread alive at all-time or create the thread when necessary.

Comment: Have you tried measuring/profiing both options?

Comment: Yes , create the thread at all time and waiting for signal from reading thread is wasting memory since thread block is memory. Otherwise creating thread from the reading loop may made the reading thread high latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern machines have hundreds, sometimes thousands of threads instantiated and in "ready" state at all times. "Ready" does not mean "Actually Running".

So, there is no problem with starting one more thread at device initialization and keeping it in "Ready" state most of the time, and giving it some work to do every once in a rare while.

The trick to getting this to work smoothly this is to make sure that the thread is block-waiting for an event to occur.  When a thread is block-waiting for a signal it is consuming zero, or near-zero, CPU.

Starting a new thread each time you need to do something can be quite costly.  A new thread usually needs to allocate memory, and this can be a time consuming operation, especially in a system that is running low on memory, where memory allocation can cause swapping.

Answer (score 2):

Just create thread once and make it block on some semaphore or mutex until you signal it. This way it won't be "always running" and it won't "be costly". This way you don't need to handle case like: "What if thread didn't start when I needed some processing" or "What if system was busy and thread startup was slow"?..

Just a minor thing: if the thread doesn't do much I would initialize it with smaller stack size.